# Fetching data from a PHP class within JS file

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I'm designing a simple login/register system(No framework) and using [justvalidate](https://just-validate.dev/) for the frontend validation and I want to fetch data from a php class to use it within the validate js file.
Here's my code.

public/assets/js/validate.js

```
    {
      validator: value => async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost/src/controllers/usercontroller/emailExists/?email=${value}`);
        const json = await response.json();
        return json.available;
      },
      errorMessage: 'Email already taken'
    }
```

src/controllers/UserController.php

```
class UserController
{
    public function __construct(private UserModel $user_gateway)
    {
    }

    public function emailExists(string $email): bool
    {
        return $this->user_gateway->emailExists($email) // returns true or false 
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if a method within a class is callable **out of a framework**. And if the query string I'm using apply in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a running php server to receive requests. Giving a file path is not gonna work as you expected. Also since you are not using any type of framework, don't create a class. Just create a standalone PHP file. Get the request parameters by $_POST or $_GET and do your thing. Then just echo your response. That echo will be picked up as a response on your javascript.

Comment: Thank you Talip for your help. That's exactly the approach I've used (mixed OOP and procedure) and it works just fine :)